# Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted - get information of webapage

Tags: php, memory, get

I'm using simple_html_dom.php, and I'm trying to get some information of some pages. But I only get half of what I want, and I get this error:

> Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 67108864 bytes exhausted (tried to
>   allocate 24 bytes) in ../simple_html_dom.php on line 1560

The code:

```
<?
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$htmlconcurso[]=value;
$html2[]=value;
$holderdes[]=value;

$html = file_get_html("http://99designs.pt/logo-design/contests?show=finished");

foreach($html->find('a[class=preview]') as $aholder) {

$htmlconcurso=$aholder->href;
//echo $aholder->href .'<br>';
$html2=file_get_html($htmlconcurso);


foreach($html2->find('small[class=menu-item__label__count]') as $aholder) {

   $holderdes=$aholder->outertext;
   //echo $holderdes; 
   echo("<script>console.log('PHP: ".$holderdes."');</script>");
}
}
?>
```

Comment: Try using `ini_set('memory_limit', '1300M');`

Comment: I have more results with that, but I have this error: Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 10 seconds exceeded in ../simple_html_dom.php on line 75

And I don't have all the results...

Comment: I got it, I change the ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);

I have problem now, the result have parentheses 
eg:
(62) 

There is any way to take the parentheses and remaining with the number?

Comment: Beside the fact this is a new question: of course there is a way. What have you tried so far?

Comment: sorry...

I try 
`preg_match_all('/([0-9]+)/',  $holderdes,$num);`

but I don't know if It's correct, and besides the result I have it's "array"